# How do I add 24 hours to a unix timestamp in php?

Tags: php, timestamp

I would like to add 24 hours to the timestamp for now. How do I find the unix timestamp number for 24 hours so I can add it to the timestamp for right now?

I also would like to know how to add 48 hours or multiple days to the current timestamp.

How can I go best about doing this?

Comment: "how to add 48 hours or multiple days" - are daylight saving times an issue?

Comment: I'd like to point out Álvaro G. Vicario's answer. Adding plain 24 hours may not be what you want in every case.

Comment: Yepp, that's why I wanted to know if zeckdude is aware of dst and if it is of some concern to him.

Answer (score 332, accepted):

You probably want to add one day rather than 24 hours. Not all days have 24 hours due to (among other circumstances) daylight saving time:

```
strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
```

Comment: The case is not so obscure, since all other code of earlier questions breaks next sunday morning. +1

Comment: My code thought March had 32 days because of this case, so it's wise to keep DST in mind unless you're operating solely in GMT.

Answer (score 107):

A Unix timestamp is simply the number of seconds since January the first 1970, so to add 24 hours to a Unix timestamp we just add the number of seconds in 24 hours. (24 * 60 *60)

```
time() + 24*60*60;
```

Comment: 24*60*60 = 86400 (might save somebody a couple seconds)

Answer (score 28):

Add `24*3600` which is the number of seconds in 24Hours

Comment: This may not work correctly when daylight savings switches from winter to summer or vice-versa

Answer (score 18):

Unix timestamp is in seconds, so simply add the corresponding number of seconds to the timestamp:

```
$timeInFuture = time() + (60 * 60 * 24);
```

Comment: No, this will not account for switch of daylight savings from summer to winter and vice-versa

Answer (score 16):

You could use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class as well:

```
$timestamp = mktime(15, 30, 00, 3, 28, 2015);

$d = new DateTime();
$d->setTimestamp($timestamp);
```

Add a **P**eriod of  **1**  **D**ay:

```
$d->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $d->format('c');
```

See [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

As you have said if you want to add 24 hours to the timestamp for right now then simply you can do:

```
 <?php echo strtotime('+1 day'); ?>
```

Above code will add 1 day or 24 hours to your current timestamp.

in place of `+1 day` you can take **whatever you want**, As **php manual** says ***[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp***.

examples from the manual are as below:

```
<?php
     echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
     echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
     echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
     echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
     echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
     echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
     echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$time = date("H:i", strtotime($today . " +5 hours +30 minutes"));
//+5 hours +30 minutes     Time Zone +5:30 (Asia/Kolkata)
```