# Convert days to unix timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add 24 hours to a unix timestamp in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515047/how-do-i-add-24-hours-to-a-unix-timestamp-in-php)

How can I convert days to a unixtimestamp?

Example if a user inputs 55 (=55 days) in a form, I wish to add 55 days, to the current time, and then store it in a unix timestamp.

Comment: http://php.net/strtotime can do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arithmetic with [`time()`](http://php.net/time):

```
$input = (int) $_POST['days'];
$timestamp = time() + $input * 86400;
```

or perhaps using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$input = (int) $_POST['days'];
$timestamp = strtotime('+' . $input ' days');
```

Answer (score 4):

The obvious solution is to say that a UNIX timestamp is in seconds, so just multiply the number of days by the number of seconds in a day (86400) and add that to the current time (`time()`).

However, if you are doing anything even slightly more complex than this, leave it to PHP to work out what "a day" means and use the [DateTime classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).  For instance:

```
$date = new DateTime('now'); // starting point
$interval = new DateInterval('P' . (int) $days . 'D'); // interval of $days days
$date->add($interval); // add the interval to the original date
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp(); // get the timestamp, or use the date in some other fashion
```

These classes are much more flexible – and, when you get to know them, much more intuitive – than doing the calculations manually.

Answer (score 0):

use `echo strtotime("+55 days");`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Time is a number with which you can calculate. Don't do unnecessary string conversions.

Comment: @GolezTrol for code readability

Comment: I'd rather write a separate function to do the calculation, and name it 'addDays' or something. More efficient *and* more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`time()` already returns a unix timestamp, which is the time in seconds since about 1970. So to add up 55 days, you should add 55 * secondsPerDay seconds.

```
$result = time() + 55 * 24 * 60 * 60; // Or 55 * 86400
```