# Adding two hours to php-timestamp-script

Tags: php, timestamp

is there a way to change this:

```
  $modtime=date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
  $timekey=date("YmdHis", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
```

Print

```
<td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'  class='files_ed_02'>$modtime</td>
```

into gmdate and adding two hours to the stamp?
Trying to show the local time for when a file was uploaded to the server.

**Edit**

Aware that this is a common question, but because gmdate() only can hold 2 parameters, it seams? this won't work

```
      $modtime=gmdate("M j Y g:i A",modtime()+(2*60*60), filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
      $timekey=gmdate("YmdHis",timekey()+(2*60*60), filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
```

Comment: How to add time to a timestamp has been asked here numerous times. Just search for it. You'll find your answer.

Comment: Useful for you: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515047/how-do-i-add-24-hours-to-a-unix-timestamp-in-php?rq=1

Comment: You are casting all your dates to strings. You simply cannot do date math with strings. It's like trying to add `'three'` and `'four'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 2 hours to the unix timestamp you get from `filemtime`:

```
$modtime=date("M j Y g:i A", (filemtime($dirArray[$index]) + (2*60 * 60));
```

You can't send it as a separate parameter, filemtime will return an integer so just add on to it.

Comment: That was just what I were looking for, thank you :)