# Check next Saturday and Sunday

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on solving a minor bug in my code, What i want the code to do is mark the next saturday and sunday and mark that row in red but the next upcomming weekends should be untouch. All efforts i have tried always ends up with marking everything in red. So i hopeing you guys are able to help me out. Don't mind the code, i know it's the old version and i'm working on converting it to 5.5 standards but this is what i have to work with atm

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tccrequest))
{
    $acdate = date('d-m-Y',time() + 86400 * $row['autoclosure']);
    if($row['ac update']!=1){
        if ($acdate <= date('d-m-Y')){
            $warning= "warning2";
        }
        else if ($acdate == date('d-m-Y')+1){
            if (date("w", strtotime("$acdate"))==6 or date("w", strtotime("$acdate"))==0){
                $warning= "warning2";
            }else{
                $warning= "nextday";
            }
        }
        else if (date("w", strtotime("$acdate"))==6 or date("w", strtotime("$acdate"))==0){
            $warning= "warning2";
        }
        else{
            $warning="";
            $disable = "disabled=\"disabled\"";
        }
    }else{
            $warning="updated";
            //$disable = "disabled=\"disabled\"";           
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause anything to be "marked in red".

Comment: $warning a class or id used by css perhaps?

Comment: You code is a little wierd. Some explanations are required. At least row structure, what is what and what do you want to achive by so many comparisons. Check them first, when debug code.

Comment: the variable $warning is calling a css line that marks red, it's the part that check the next upcomming weekends that i'm struggling with

Comment: The idea is as follows, 
In the DB i have x amount of rows with dates from today until 3-4 weeks ahead (depending on the submitted data) and currently the code marks todays date as Red on each line that have todays date. Also it marks tomorrows date as yellow. What i also have added is marking saturday and sunday as Red. Currently it's marking all saturdays and sundays but i only want it to mark the next saturday and sunday. And since i dont want to hardcode all the dates by hand (since they change next year) im looking for a function that does this for me in an easier way.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, i solved the code and posted it in the below box. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem of getting exact dates that need to be "market in red" and than do with what what you want? As I understand, you need to "mark" only next sun/sat, so only two values. Right?

In this case, you can eighter do php check, like

```
if ($current_date_from_my_sql_row == $next_sat) or ($current_date_from_my_sql_row == $next_sun)
{
   echo "<h2 color='red'>This is in red</h2>"
}
```

or you can simply put it into your sql query like
SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE data=$next_sat OR data=$next_sun
It will give you only required values.

Comment: Well the problem is that it loops out 2 weeks of content and i'm trying to determand the next sat and sun. I was experimenting with strtotime('next sunday', $date) but that did not work so well

So basicly what i want to do is mark the next Calendar Sat and Sun but not the next week. Is there a good code to use to do this since if i would loop out a whole year of content i do not want it to mark all Sat and sun, just the next two inline

Comment: Why what I wrote does not fit you? Calculate 2 dates and compare? You mark next calendar Sat and Sun.

Comment: Yes i was along that line, but since i have no clue which date is the next sat or sun i was looking for a feature that fetches the next weekend and only that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712761/how-to-find-day-of-week-in-php
"Since php 5.1.0 you can use date("N", $timestamp) to get 1..7 values starting from Monday."
$dw =  date("N", $timestamp); // timestamp - your date from database
$shift_sat = 6 - $dw; // How much do you need to add to get saturday
$shift_sun = 7 - $dw; // How much do you need to add to get sunday
if ($shift_sat <= 1) // decide, what you if date is weekends...
strtotime('+$shift_sat day', $timestamp);

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515047/how-do-i-add-24-hours-to-a-unix-timestamp-in-php

Try it.

Comment: Ah man it was so simple i was just to blind to see it, i made two variables outside of the while loop named 
$nextSaturday = date("d-m-Y", strtotime('next saturday'));
$nextSunday = date("d-m-Y", strtotime('next sunday'));
And just did a date check with the corresponding row if it was next sat or sun and it worked like a charm. Thank you for hinting me about the code. Without it i would have stared into oblivion until it stared back at me. Man i miss having people to just talk programming with, thanks once again.